# Is the opacity of CATransformLayer supposed to be passed onto its children?

Tags: ios, cocoa, calayer, catransformlayer

I have a card view with a front and a back. The front and back are `CALayer`s composed in a `CATranformLayer`. The back layer is transformed to flip it to face the right direction, and then moved in the z direction to be slightly behind the front.

[image: Two CALayers layered on-top of one another (the lowest layer being horizontally flipped), contained by a CATransformLayer]

When I adjust the opacity of the parent `CATransformLayer` from 1.0 to 0.0, I expect to see the front-facing side fade-out, but instead am seeing both sides blending and fading out together.

I had previously fixed this by setting both sides's `doublesided` property to `NO`, but this elicited a warning:

```
<CATransformLayer: 0x174227500> - changing property doubleSided in transform-only layer, will have no effect
```

…thing is, it does have an effect. Setting `doublesided` to no prevents the blending of the layers on fade out. Here's what happens when `doublesided` isn't set (and defaults to `YES`):

[image]

Is this a bug with `CATransformLayer` or is my understanding off?

Here's [a gist of the problem](https://gist.github.com/warpling/672261ad0a15558ae8d8) as well.